# NPM installation problem In Laravel in Windows 10

Tags: npm, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, package.json

### My NPM ver is 5.6.0 My Node ver is v8.11.3 Laravel Framework 5.7.12

### I have some Problems When i want to install The npm in laravel which are as follows

```
npm install
```

> npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
>
> npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.

```
node-sass@4.10.0 install C:\xampp\htdocs\Newapp\node_modules\node-sass

node scripts/install.js
```

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> npm WARN img-loader@3.0.1 requires a peer of imagemin@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! node-sass@4.10.0 install: node scripts/install.js
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.10.0 install script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR! C:\Users\bamas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-11-07T03_33_04_531Z-debug.log

### MY package.json is

```
{ "private": true, "scripts": { "dev": "npm run development", "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js", "watch": "npm run development -- --watch", "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll", "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js", "prod": "npm run production", "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js" }, "devDependencies": { "axios": "^0.18", "bootstrap": "^4.0.0", "cross-env": "^5.1", "jquery": "^3.2", "laravel-mix": "^2.0", "lodash": "^4.17.5", "popper.js": "^1.12", "vue": "^2.5.17" } }
```

### I already tried everithing like cache clear re installing nodemodules but its not effect.. My NPM is alright Because whenever i run my other Nodejs script it work perfectly i am using gitbash....

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Any luck resolving it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This is my solution! **Try cleaning the cache with the command**

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and retry with

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To solve it: rollback to NPM Version 5.6.0.

```
# npm install -g npm@5.6.0
```

To Verify:

```
# npm -v
```

Note: I had to clear the cache, remove all files under node_modules, and package-lock.json.